# using template ( same result)

Tags: c++, templates

Why is the output of these two programs the same?

Example 1

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
T1 sumit(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    T2 result = (a + b);
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    cout << sumit(1, 'a');
}
```

Example 2

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
T1 sumit(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    T1 result = (a + b);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << sumit(1, 'a');
}
```

What is deference between T1 result and T2 result?

Comment: Please take the time to clean up your examples. Presenting messy or oddly formatted code (including excessive white space or indentation) will turn many users away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either case you are passing first argument as an int and second as char. So, T1 becomes `int` and T2 becomes `char`.

In first case you are storing the result of `a+b` in a char variable (as T2 here is a char), but while returning the result it becomes an int. In your code you are just adding `1` and `'a'` and ASCII value of 'a' is 97. So the returned result is 98. Both `char` and `int` returns same answer here because a `char` can also store 98 (char is 1 byte and its range is -128 to 127; int is 4 bytes).

In your second program you are storing the sum in an int variable (as T1 is `int`), which can definitely store the sum of `1+'a'` which is 98 (int value).

So you are getting same result in both the cases.

If you had added some large `int` value instead of `1` the returned result by both the programs would differ. For example, if you pass `1200 and 'a'` to sumit() function, then the first program will return `17` due to overflow of `char` range but second program will return `1297` (no overflow in case of int).

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are creating a T2 item, and then returning it as a T1 item (as per the function signature).  In the second program, you are creating a T1 item and returning it as a T1 item.  In both cases, a T1 is being returned, and not a T2.

Comment: @utsav_deep I never said they were equivalent, just that both are returning T1 values, which in this example is an int.

Comment: Deleted my comment after realising this.